# Control Android device from PC

Tags: remote-control, vnc

I have built an Android app which is locked in landscape orientation. I want to have a live view of my mobile on my PC to make a demonstration of my app. The problem is that the screen doesn't show properly.

I have tested some apps like Droid VNC Server and Airdroid but the problem is that my app's screen is rotated 90 degrees and it seems that these apps were showing my landscape app in portrait mode.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try using [TeamViewer for Remote Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.teamviewer.market.mobile). It offers Screen cast functionality.

> Provide technical remote support to your android devices using the TeamViewer QuickSupport app and the TeamViewer Host app for Android.

Examples of what the app enables you to do include pushing Wi-Fi settings to the device, transferring files to the device, or controlling the device remotely. Remote control (in the classical sense of a TeamViewer remote control session) is currently available for devices from the following manufacturers:

- Samsung
- Sony
- Acer
- Asus (for business customers)
- Lenovo
- LG
- HTC
- ZTE

Answer (score 2):

My experiences were the best with [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy).

It works over an adb connection, but this adb connection can happen both on an USB connection, and also over wifi (for really hardcore guys, even over VPN).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at the droidVNC-NG project. The Android VNC server app [droidVNC-NG](https://github.com/bk138/droidVNC-NG) reached version 1.0.0 in early 2021 and we are now looking for contributors to further improve the code and add features.

Answer (score 1):

There are many apps for remote controlling Android mobile. You can also try screencasting. Windows 10 has pre-installed software for Android screen mirroring.

1. On Windows 10, click on Start / Connect. You can check here about your device's remote connect support.
2. Turn on Wi-Fi and Bluetooth on a Windows computer and mobile.
   Go to Settings (<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>) / Devices. Add Bluetooth devices.
3. Select Wireless Display.
4. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to project the Windows' screen.

   [image: windows 10 screen mirror]
5. Select duplicate. Your computer screen appears on mobile.

On Google Chrome, you can get add-on tools for connecting mobile and computer. Chrome Remote Desktop and TeamViewer are the apps you can use.