# Add WiFi connection settings for an Android device using computer

Tags: wi-fi

How do we setup WiFi connection settings for an Android device using a computer?

Comment: I think the only way would be to use one of the apps recommended in http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45289/control-android-device-from-pc to control the phone and input the settings into the GUI in the usual way.

Comment: Why are you not using the device itself?

Comment: Also which direction is the internet coming from? From or To PC? Are you wanting to tether the connection or what are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @rrirower I'm using the device itself but I want to try setting it up via computer.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN From PC. I just want to try setting up the connection settings of the phone via computer.